# How can I host React Native code on Expo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo, hybrid-mobile-app

I am creating a website where my customers can create a single page website and a simple mobile app (android + IOS).
For providing mobile apps, I am creating 2-3 themes for mobile apps. and I need to create my client's mobile apps changing minor things like name, icon, logo etc.
I want to skip commend line process, for creating mobile app form theme.

so my questions are:

1. can I host multiple mobile app theme code in expo or any other platform?
2. If yes, then what is price for this service?

Comment: You can publish your mobile app project in Expo for free,  and if your app is production-ready then you can host it in the play store or app store

Comment: can I host multiple project at the same time? @AyushKumar

Comment: Of course. Here is the link for the [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/) of the expo